# How is the right way to restore Inapppurchases of non-consumable products in combination with server?

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase

This is a question to understand a basic procedure.

Apple says in his Guidelines that you have to add a restore button to your app. 
this makes sense if the user, for example, uninstalled the app.

In my case, the users have to log in before they buy. For this the app asks for my server with ajax. When logged in, the user have the option of purchasing a non-consumable product.

If the purchase was successful, the product will be unlocked on my server and the user will have access.

Now I wonder what the restore button should do. if the user uninstalls the app, he can login normally, because my server knows that the product has already been purchased.

it is only problematic if something goes wrong between purchase and transfer to my server. then the information of the successful purchase is missing on my server.

But if you would give the user the option to restore the product on my server after the login, then you could unlock an unlimited number of accounts with this device.

So my question is: how is the right way for restoring in combination with a server?

Comment: You should validate the receipt with your server.  If the user attempts to restore purchases and the receipt matches an existing (different) user on your server, don't activate the IAP.

Comment: Still one question. I thought about it. I think your solution are heavy functions to the server. If I have more than 50.000 users or something, I cannot check every user, What do you think? ist there another option?

Comment: It is pretty trivial to search an sql database of even 50,000 rows of you have an index on the transaction id column.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will give a try.